# Reading or getting a command from console thread

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, command, getline

I have a program in c++ with several threads in it. I want one of the threads to be able to read/get commands from the console while others continue running, for example: "play", "stop", "pause",...

something like:

```
while (1)
{

    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);

    /* do something */

}
```

Will it work? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as they don't use std::cin at the same time :)

Comment: This is probably too broad to be addressed correctly

Comment: Since you already have the program with the threads, why don't you just try it? Either that, or ask a more sensible question than "will it work?". What exactly is it you're unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes.

Long Answer: It depends of what you call 'work', there is nothing that prevent you from calling a blocking function/method from a thread while other threads are running.

However, threads share memory and resources. On an UNIX machine (and it's more or less the same on Windows), stdin and stdout are shared between threads. std::cin will manipulate stdin under the hood at some point, and you should ensure that **only one thread can manipulate a given resource at a time**.

You can do that by either make sure that only one thread can reach code using std::cin, or use synchronization, with a mutex/semaphore.